# How to fix "Unpermitted parameter: :avatar" error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to allow user to upload image with carrierwave gem from a form_for but I got this error:

> Unpermitted parameter: :avatar

(see full stack trace below)

I'm using devise gem so I have to add strong parameter in application_controller as the documentation says but it doesn't work.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    attributes = [:name, :email, :avatar]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: attributes)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: attributes)
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :ensure_admin, :except => :show

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  private

  def ensure_admin
    if(current_user.role == 'admin')
      return
    end
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access denied."
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :role, :email, :name, :password)
  end
end
```

my view:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :avatar %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label I18n.translate('user.current_password') %> <i><%= I18n.translate('user.needed_to_confirm') %></i>
  <%= f.password_field :current_password, placeholder: I18n.translate('user.current_password'), autocomplete: "current-password", class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit I18n.translate('control.update'), class: 'form-control btn sign-up-button' %>
</div>
```

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_07_30_090404) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "name"
    t.text "image"
    t.string "role"
    t.string "avatar"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
end
```

full stack trace:

> Started PUT "/users?locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-08-02 11:23:40
>   +0200 Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"k4pnLdkhc9sFOLax51vkSv0SA8SfnL7Niw3gfo60nmLfBS1I7FD25P54Q/1qzF4aHIFiBtvq5TzLKk1/LwZHzw==",
>   "user"=>{"name"=>"Clovis5", "email"=>"clovi@clovi.com",
>   "avatar"=>#,
>   @original_filename="IMG_20190712_150908_155__01.jpg",
>   @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"user[avatar]\";
>   filename=\"IMG_20190712_150908_155__01.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type:
>   image/jpeg\r\n">, "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update", "locale"=>"en"}
>   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =
>   $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
>   /Users/clovisgenevard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
>   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =
>   $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
>   /Users/clovisgenevard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
>   Unpermitted parameter: :avatar    (0.1ms)  BEGIN   ↳
>   /Users/clovisgenevard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
>   (0.1ms)  COMMIT   ↳
>   /Users/clovisgenevard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
>   Unpermitted parameter: :avatar Unpermitted parameter: :avatar
>   Unpermitted parameter: :avatar Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/?locale=en Completed 302 Found in 137ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Comment: `@user.update_attribute(:avatar)` no need of this line in update action

Comment: and make sure that you have `mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader` in your user model

Comment: There is mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader in my user model

Comment: Could you post more of the stack trace? That will tell us which controller and action are rejecting the parameter.

Comment: thank you I posted more of the stack trace.